# ejs tags inside html are not working stop my server I keep getting yellow lines indicating there's errors

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= block ('title') %></title>
</head>
<% extends "layouts/layout.ejs" %>

<%= block('content'), function(){=%>
<body>
    <%= body =%>

    
</body>
<%= });  %>
</html>
```

I've tried changing the syntax and add extra parameters in settings.json but still not working. I have installed all the right dependancies etc but still not working.
how can I get this to work, I am trying to get the layouts page to work so that contents from other pages can be rendered.

Comment: Do you see any error(s) in your developer console?

Comment: no I don't see any error in my developer console

Comment: only when I run I get this: inalyearproject/views/layouts/layouts.ejs:8
    6|         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    7|         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 >> 8|         <title><%- block ('title') %></title>
    9|     </head>
    10|     <body>
    11|         <%- block('content') %>

block is not defined